# Fixar o rodapé de uma página html e acompanhar o conteúdo da página

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Eu preciso fixar a tag `footer` no final da página html, mas quando o conteúdo exceder a página a tag `footer` deve acompanhar o conteúdo e não ficar fixa.

Veja o código CSS é o código HTML que estou usando para isso.

```css
    header {
        min-height: 55px; /* original era 255px mudei para caber no snippet */
        background-color: blue;
    }
    article {
        padding-bottom: 60px; 
        width: 900px; 
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    footer {
        position: absolute; 
        bottom: 0px; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 60px; 
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<header></header>

<article>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>    
</article>

<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

O problema é que a tag `footer` com a propriedade `position` com o valor `fixed` deixa o rodapé fixo.

Quando mudo a propriedade `position` para `absolute` a tag `footer` fica flutuando e não acompanha o conteúdo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para *browsers* recentes você pode adicionar isto ao seu CSS:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 60px; /* altura do seu footer */
}
```

Segundo [o criador](http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/) da solução, functiona com: **IE8+**, **Chrome / Safari**, **Firefox** e **Opera**.

A maior vantagem desta solução sobre as outras é que você não precisa criar *wrappers* em volta do seu conteúdo. Ela utiliza o próprio `body` como *wrapper*.

#### Exemplo: [**`Com muito conteúdo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/X3d2w/) - [**`Sem muito conteúdo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/MAwG7/)

*<sup>(O mesmo código foi utilizado para os dois exemplos, só o conteúdo que muda.)</sup>*

Answer (score 5):

Da para fazer usando `flex` no `body`.

Primeiro vc precisa definir o `body` com `display: flex`, depois coloca a ordem como `column`, para que a "orientação" do grid fique na vertical (mais ou menos como o comportamento padrão das `divs`). Depois no `main` que vai receber o conteúdo vc coloca `flex-grow: 1;` e coloca `position:sticky` na `nav` para ela ficar fixa no topo. Dessa forma o `main` vai sempre ocupar todo o espaço disponível, "empurrando" o `footer` sempre pro final da página independente da quantidade de conteúdo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Veja o código usado para ter o resultado da imagem acima:**

***Exipa também como "`Página toda`" para ver melhor o resultado!***

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: #ddd;
}
nav, 
footer {
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 50px;
 background-color: #f00;
 text-align: center;
 color: #ddd;
}
nav {
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}
main {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: turquoise;
 flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>NAV</nav>
<main>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur voluptates reprehenderit magni molestias iure unde id minima voluptatem laudantium ipsum. Nam reprehenderit iusto consectetur ipsum natus doloremque laudantium illum quod delectus perferendis! Quam explicabo laudantium suscipit reprehenderit harum quo nostrum porro fugit natus. Eius sequi odit sunt, aut eveniet similique dicta mollitia reprehenderit incidunt, molestiae quod amet esse facere vero perspiciatis dignissimos voluptatum eligendi laborum dolorum asperiores inventore, ipsum est. Obcaecati dolores perspiciatis dignissimos. Consequuntur soluta quaerat, asperiores sed earum non impedit. Tempora dicta dolorum quas id asperiores laboriosam delectus velit perferendis veniam blanditiis ea exercitationem ullam, ab consequuntur incidunt ipsa est voluptate suscipit cumque non ipsum praesentium minima aliquam. Tempore ratione dolore aut saepe sint. Eos vel facilis minima nostruoloremque reprehenderit nisi sunt inventore maxime quisquam quaerat, totam perspiciatis. Quidem in sint debitis perspiciatis labore, eaque nam quis doloremque blanditiis ipsum architecto temporibus sunt tempore voluptates? Voluptatem, dolorum unde ut facilis quasi eligendi officia earum in. Nemo impedit pariatur itaque soluta non minus. Minima vel maiores aliquid officiis accusamus optio excepturi praesentium in doloremque, similique necessitatibus! Iure asperiores necess nemo ipsa laborum velit optio 
</main>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

**OBS:** O `Flex` funciona do IE10 pra cima https://caniuse.com/#search=flex aténde

Answer (score -2):

Uma solução simples e responsiva seria assim.

```css
footer{
position: relative;
background-color: red;
width:100%;
height:48px;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<header></header>

<article>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p> 
</article>

<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Se houver pouco conteúdo na página, o rodapé não ficará fixado na parte de baixo: https://jsfiddle.net/b8gze2ta/

Comment: Acrescente no css

left: 0;
bottom: 0;

Assim:

`footer{
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
width:100%;
height:48px;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
}`

Answer (score -2):

Para que o  Caso tenha pouco conteúdo na pagina não se desloque para acompanhar o conteúdo use  `{left: 0; bottom: 0;}`

```css
footer{
position: relative;
background-color: red;
width:100%;
height:48px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>

<article>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>
  <p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p><p>Conteúdo</p>    
</article>

<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seu código não está legal, basta vc executar ai e fazer um scroll que vc vai ver que o Footer fica no meio da página e o conteúdo continua após ele

Comment: Foi porque havia me esquecido de ajustar o position. Quando o conteúdo for grande não use o `left:` ou `bottom`. Quando o Conteúdo for curto ou pouco use-os assim `left:0; bottom:0` `positon`  deve ser **relative**