# Como fazer um header com imagem de fundo

Tags: css, css3

Preciso montar um layout com a seguinte estrutura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde a parte azul vai ser uma imagem.

```
<header class="header-bg">
<div class="logo">
  <span>Logo</span>
</div>

<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
    <li><a href="#produtos">Produtos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<p> BLA BLA BLA </p>
```

A parte do menu eu acho que posso usar `flexbox`, e colocar um `space-between` para deixar a `logo` e o `menu` cada um em um canto, porém não sei como colocar uma imagem de fundo nisso, que acabe no inicio do conteúdo do site (na imagem o sobre) e não sei como posicionar o `P` (BLA BLA BLA) no meio, talvez utilizando um `margin: 0 auto` porém não sei se é a melhor maneira.

Comment: `background-image: url(caminho_da_imagem);`

Comment: Vc está usando algum Framework tipo Bootstrap ou está fazendo tudo na mão?

Comment: @hugocsl Tudo na mão, mas posso utilizar BS sem problemas

Comment: @Sam Colocar a imagem eu sei, não sei fazer do jeito que falei no post

Comment: Tá certo jovem rs... é que na pergunta vc é bem contundente ao dizer que não sabe como colocar uma imagem de fundo. :D

Comment: Vou fazer um modelo na mão, pq pra isso não precisa do BS, além disso é mais divertido na mão :D. Mas se o seu projeto for grande as vezes um Framework pode ser interessante...

Comment: @Sam Verdade, me expressei mal. O que eu quis dizer na verdade era colocar a imagem de fundo mesmo :D com os elementos em cima dela

Comment: @hugocsl Agradeço amigo, mas se fica melhor com um framework sem problemas também, pensei em talvez o Bulma pela questão de ser mais leve, acho o BS muito pesado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segue um exemplo, sei que alguns propriedades estão repetidas e poderiam ser otimizadas, mas preferir deixar individualmente para facilitar o seu entendimento, mesmo ficando com umas linhas a mais de código. Basicamente usei `flex` para fazer tudo então ficou bem responsivo.

Segue o código:

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40%;
 min-height: 250px;
 background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/300/200);
 background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: relative;
} 
nav  {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
nav ul {
 padding: 0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 color: #fff;
}
nav ul li {
 list-style: none;
}
header section {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
header section h2 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <nav>
  <img src="https://placecage.com/100/50" alt="">
  <ul>
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
   <li>item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <section>
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
 </section>
</header>
<main>
 <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h1>
</main>
```

Comment: Obrigado @hugocsl, me ajudou muito.

Comment: É o Nicolas Cage alí? XD

Comment: @AndreiCoelho sim haha, tem o placecage.com e o fillmurray.com são meus dois cdn de imagem preferidos :D. Sobre o código ele não eh tão refinado, mas eh uma base que vc pode usar pra muitos modelos de layout. Se vc quiser um modelo com header e fixo e footer dinâmico as vezes vc pode tentar juntar esse layout com esse outro https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19531/fixar-o-rodapé-de-uma-página-html-e-acompanhar-o-conteúdo-da-página/349962#349962 []'s

Comment: Acabei de visitar os sites! kkkk